# Wrap expanding text around image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with wraping the `img`, when `div` is expanded on button click. Without styles of `myDiv` it wraps ok.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img width='300px' src='http://freefunnydogpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/picture_1400053660.jpg'/>
    <div class='myDiv'>Утверждён Перечень сельскохозяйственной продукции, сырья и продовольствия, страной происхождения которых являются Соединенные Штаты Америки, страны Европейского союза,... 
    </div>
</div>
<button id='myButton'>Click</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        $('.myDiv').height(500);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
img{
    float:left;
}

.myDiv{
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pfodox/z05cwh5g/.

Comment: The text's height needs to be the same as the image? And when you click the button just show it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the button's click function as follows.

```
   $('#myButton').click(function(){
      $('.myDiv').css('height','auto'); 
      // The above line will increase the height of div automatically 
      //and avoids overlapping with other elements
      $('#myButton').css('display','none');
      $('.myDiv').css('overflow','visible');
   });
```

Instead of changing the height hard-coded, change the "overflow" property. Because this is the one which you must reset if the text needs to get wrapped around the image. Set it to 'visible' or 'inherit'. - http://jsfiddle.net/vivek_nk/z05cwh5g/3/

Comment: Ok, but what if I'll have 2 elements like this stocked. Top one will overlaying the bottom one.

Comment: In that case height must be set to 'auto'. $('.myDiv').css('height','auto'); in that function

Comment: What about this for start: `$('.myDiv').height($('img').height());`. Then onClick, `$('.myDiv').css({'overflow':'visible', 'height': 'auto'});`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `overflow:hidden` from `myDiv` class

Comment: But I need text to be hidden.

Comment: so your requirement is to hide content when it exceeds beyond div size??

Comment: I need hidden text, but show it on button click + wrap arround img

Comment: one way would be to keep your styling as is and apply overflow:inherit  to div class on button click

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more than just the text-align.  Your issue is with having the text wrapped in a DIV.  Furthermore, floating auto-wraps.

I don't know of a simple way to do what you're asking, but you may want to look into http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/.

Edit:
Here's a variation of vivek_nk's code, in case you need to keep the button as a toggle to collapse the content again: http://jsfiddle.net/tsukasadt/xnd544k1/

Here's the jQuery toggle function:

```
$('#myButton').toggle(function () {
    $('.myDiv').css('height','auto');
    $('.myDiv').css('overflow','visible');
}, function () {
    $('.myDiv').css('height','100px');
    $('.myDiv').css('overflow','hidden');
});
```

I requires you move the button inside the outer DIV and replace the entire jQuery function, but it'll leave the button on the page as a toggle between the CSS for overflow hidden/visible and height 100px/auto.